# how to do Javascript server side profiling or function trace?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have Node.js application, and the server side javascript code i have written taking lot of time.

What is the way to do profiling on each method and check how much time its taking.

Comment: Have you looked at Dtrace?

Comment: The Node.js blog includes some suggestions: [Profiling Node.js](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/04/25/profiling-node-js/)